# android list view

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am new to Android, I'm using ListView to retrieve the values from an Android sqlite database.
In the ListView, I want to delete it when I press a button. Can anybody help me with this problem? Any Help would be appreciated...

Comment: How can you delete a list view from a list view?

Comment: You can delete an element from a list view.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean deleteItem(String itemName) {
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_NAME + "=?", new String[]{itemName});
}
```